Return rows that only have nulls?
I'm using Kusto/KQL. I have a huge dataset that I am working with that was migrated from another sources. I know that many of the fields only have null values. I'd like to be able to identify those columns. Sort of doing a null check on column by column, is there a way I can find out what columns never have any data?

Please clarify your question. Are you looking for empty columns (which you can project away), empty rows (for deletion), or non-empty rows (for querying)?


Return rows that only have nulls?

You can below KQl query:
let rithTable = datatable(Col1:string, Date:datetime, Col2:string, Col3:string, Col4:string, C0l5:string, Col6:string)
[
    "Test", datetime(2028-09-08), "Tp", "", "", "DK", "",
    "Chotu", datetime(2028-09-04), "w", "hn", "some", "some", "some",
    "Val", datetime(2028-09-02), "nI", "RR", "bb", "c", "ok",
    "Rithwik", datetime(2028-08-12), "", "", "", "", "kk",
    "Bojja", datetime(2028-09-7), "", "dk", "", "", ""
];
let Test1 = rithTable
| serialize 
| extend Row = row_number()- 1;
Test1
| evaluate narrow()  
| where isnull(Value) or Value == "" 
| project Row 
| distinct Row
| join kind=inner (Test1) on Row
| sort by Row asc 
| project-away Row,Row1

Output:

Fiddle.
Alternatively, you can directly give the column names with isnull().
let rithTable = datatable(Col1:string, Date:datetime, Col2:string, Col3:string, Col4:string, Col5:string, Col6:string)
[
    "Test", datetime(2028-09-08), "Tp", "", "", "DK", "",
    "Chotu", datetime(2028-09-04), "w", "hn", "some", "some", "some",
    "Val", datetime(2028-09-02), "nI", "RR", "bb", "c", "ok",
    "Rithwik", datetime(2028-08-12), "", "", "", "", "kk",
    "Bojja", datetime(2028-09-7), "", "dk", "", "", ""
];
rithTable
| where isnull(Col1) or Col1 == "" or isnull(Col2) or Col2 == "" or isnull(Col3) or Col3 == "" or isnull(Col4) or Col4 == "" or isnull(Col5) or Col5 == "" or isnull(Col6) or Col6 == "" 

Output:

Fiddle.
